# Appending data to paginator result

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-paginator

How can I execute and append data to elements of $paginator before returning it to the view?
I can't execute the query in the Controller or the TableGateway. 
I need to append other results based on the results of my paginator.

Comment: What did you try already? What did you observe? If so, which errors occurred? Please give a more detailed question and welcome to SO :)

Comment: In “public function fetch All” I have tried to execute the $pagination object so I can traverse the array an append data too it. 

It seems to be the wrong way of doing things. Because I can’t execute the query within $pagination.

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to append? It sounds like you would better off looking at modifying your "fetchAll"-function.

Comment: I'v solved the problem using $resultSet->buffer();